# mat table with two sticky headers and sticky footer first two columns sticky horizontal scroll showing data

Tags: angular-material-table, angular14

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Isy.png)

I have mat table with two sticky headers, sticky footer and first two columns sticky. When I horizontally scroll it showing data between two columns like in the attached image.

I have tried all the suggestions posted here https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15885 it's not helpful.

please help me on this. Thanks in advance.